# Remove XML Namespaces from action Result

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, .net-core

Using Web API and .NET Core and when I return an XML result I get the following:

```
    <Test xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <Response>
        <Status>0</Status>
    </Response>
</Test>
```

How do I remove the namespaces?

Here's part of my startup.cs file

```
 services
            .AddMvc(config =>
            {
                // Add XML Content Negotiation
                config.RespectBrowserAcceptHeader = true;
                config.InputFormatters.Add(new XmlSerializerInputFormatter());
                config.OutputFormatters.Add(new XmlSerializerOutputFormatter(new XmlWriterSettings
                {
                    OmitXmlDeclaration = true,

                }));
            })
            .AddXmlDataContractSerializerFormatters()
            .AddXmlSerializerFormatters()
            .AddMvcOptions(opt => opt.FormatterMappings.SetMediaTypeMappingForFormat("xml", new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/xml")));
```

Comment: Did you try it with RTM? Still using RC1/RC2 when the RTM is already out for a while doesn't sound like a good plan. Better migrate, maybe it's fixed in RTM

Comment: I should have mentioned that I am using RTM.

Comment: My mistake. I confused it with some stuff that was removed from RTM. Did you remove previous OutputFormatters? i.e. by calling `.OutputFormatters.Clear()` before you add it? I assume `.AddXmlSerializerFormatters()` already adds the formatter so your options are probably not taking effect

Comment: At least the `AddXmlSerializerFormatters()` calls https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/1.0.0/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Xml/DependencyInjection/MvcXmlMvcCoreBuilderExtensions.cs#L59-L60 the `MvcXmlSerializerMvcOptionsSetup` which adds https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/1.0.0/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Xml/Internal/MvcXmlSerializerMvcOptionsSetup.cs#L28-L29

Comment: Alternatively worth to try `var outputFormatter = options.OutputFormatters.OfType<XmlSerializerOutputFormatter>().Single()` to get the first item of type `XmlSerializerOutputFormatter` and then set it's property `outputFormatter.WriterSettings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both `XmlSerializer` and `DataContractSerializer` formatters look for `Content-Type` or `Accept` header values for `application/xml` and `text/xml`. So if you register both the first formatters its possible that only one formatter in them would take effect.

If you want to support XmlSerializer, then register only that formatter and if you want to support both for some reason, make sure to change the content-types they look for. Example: application/xml-dcs, text/xml-dcs, application/xml-xmlser, text/xml-ser

In case of above issue, DataContractSerializerOutputFormatter is probably writing out the response and hence you are not seeing it take effect.